# Error: reduceRegions is not a function in Google Earth Engine

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

I'm trying to get population density data from Google Earth Engine but i get an error.

> Line 17: gpw_roi.reduceRegions is not a function

```
// Load GPW population count dataset
var gpw = ee.ImageCollection('CIESIN/GPWv4/population-count');

// Define the area of interest (AOI) using a polygon geometry
var aoi = ee.Geometry.Polygon([
  [-74.1, 40.6],
  [-74.1, 40.7],
  [-73.9, 40.7],
  [-73.9, 40.6],
]);

// Filter the GPW dataset to the AOI
var gpw_roi = gpw.filterBounds(aoi);

// Function to calculate population for each feature in the collection
var calculatePopulation = function(feature) {
  var population = gpw_roi.reduceRegions({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    collection: feature.geometry(),
    scale: 1000, // Scale in meters (adjust based on your area size and resolution)
  });
  return feature.set('population_count', population.first().get('population-count'));
};

// Map the function over the FeatureCollection and calculate population for each area
var populationCounts = gpw_roi.map(calculatePopulation);

// Print the population counts
print('Population Counts:', populationCounts);
```

What could be wrong with the script? How can i get the population count?

Answer (score 0):

`gpw_roi` is an `ee.ImageCollection`. `reduceRegions` is an operation on single `ee.Image`s, not `ee.ImageCollection`s.

Before you can apply `reduceRegions` you must select a single image or combine multiple images. It looks like you tried to map over *each image of* `gpw_roi`, but you didn't use the right variable name. Change this line:

```js
  var population = gpw_roi.reduceRegions({
```

to

```js
  var population = feature.reduceRegions({
```

Now the code works. However, since `feature` is the *image*, not your `aoi`, `collection: feature.geometry()` probably won't be the region you wanted. Also, since you have only one polygon, `reduceRegions` is not needed and `reduceRegion` is more applicable. Consider doing this instead:

```js
var calculatePopulation = function(image) {
  var population = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: aoi,
    scale: 1000,
  });
  return image.set('population_count', population.get('population-count'));
};
```

(In addition to the changes I already mentioned, I renamed the mapping variable to `image` since it is an image.)

This will sum the values over the bounds of `aoi`, not the bounds of the image, which is probably what you meant.

However, there's one more problem left: this will *not* give you a precise population count. Instead, it samples the input image on an 1 km grid (`scale: 1000`) which is not necessarily the pixel grid of the original image, so it doesn't give you the population count within `aoi`, but a sum of those samples. Instead, you should leave out the `scale` parameter, so that it counts all of the original image's pixels within the bounds. Since [the image's documented resolution](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/CIESIN_GPWv4_population-count) is "30 arc-second (approximately 1km) grid cells", this is *almost* the same value, but you might as well be precise and make your code *simpler* by leaving out the scale.

```js
var calculatePopulation = function(image) {
  var population = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: aoi,
  });
  return image.set('population_count', population.get('population-count'));
};
```